# C++ For Loops, Multi-Dimensional Arrays, and Pointers Exercise

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

My main question is:

Is there a better (or more efficient) way to declare a multidimensional array using pointers? Am I on the right track with what I've done?

Programming Exercise:

You sell the book *C++ for Fools*. Use a two-dimensional array to store input for 3 years of monthly sales (in terms of number of books, not of money). Report the total sales for the combined years. The program should use a loop to prompt you by month, using an array of string objects, initialized to the month strings and storing the input data in two-dimensional array. Then, the program should find the sum of the array contents and report the total sales for the 3 years.

This is a **SNIPPET** of my code:

```
/* Global constants */
const unsigned int YRS = 3;
const unsigned int MNTHS = 12;

/* Create 2D-Array */
int** bookSalesArrayPtr = new int*[YRS];    // Pointer-to-Array-of-Pointers
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < YRS; ++i)      // Each element of bookSalesArrayPtr
    bookSalesArrayPtr[i] = new int[MNTHS];  // In each element create new array[12]
```

Here is a link to my complete source code: http://ideone.com/LcQeuj

Comment: I understand that I can use a 2D array declared outside any function (global) and eliminate the need for pointers. Besides the global declaration way, and the way I did it in my code: what other ways are there? I am in an Introduction to Structured Programming course (not a full-on OOP course). Beginner programming.

Comment: You can declare the array as global, and you can eliminate the pointers. But these things have nothing to do with each other, you can do both, or either one, or none. The way you have chosen is the typical way using pointers. The only other way that occurs to me is to allocate your second dimension as one allocation of YRS*MNTHS integers instead of YRS allocations of MNTHS integers.

Comment: @john: you mean to create one large block, instead of an official 2D array? I did that and it worked, but my professor specifically wants a 2D array, so I had to find a different solution.  Thank you, john.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of (apologies for the lack of formatting). `int** bookSalesArrayPtr = new int*[YRS]; int* largeBlock = new int[YRS*MNTHS]; for (unsigned int i = 0; i < YRS; ++i) bookSalesArrayPtr[i] = &largeBlock[i*MNTHS];` It's the same as your version in structure, but arguably optimized because it only makes two allocations

Answer (score -1):

Any solution should be *as simple as possible*.  If pointers are not required, then avoid pointers as they tend to complicate programs:

```
int  bookSales[YRS][MNTHS];
```

Notice how easy to read this is.  Notice how there is no code to manage allocation, destruction, or any other bookkeeping.

Even if such a structure increased execution time (and that is extremely improbable here), consider how much human time (developer, maintainer, debugger, documentation) this saves.  Computer time is cheap.  Human time is valuable.

When rating a solution, it is all too common to overlook the human costs.

Comment: +1, just because. There's not one thing, not one single thing, wrong with this style. For one thing, it keeps the memory compact, which is very important when one starts using complex matrix algorithms. For another, it avoids memory pointers and it avoids memory allocation.

Comment: There is everything wrong with this style. Use `std::array` (which is just as “compact” as C-style arrays). There is no reason ever in C++ to use C-style arrays. Also see http://codepuppy.co.uk/cpptuts/CClass/CArrays.aspx.

Comment: BS. There's no need for either `std::vector` or `std::array` here. An array of arrays or a vector of vectors is very suboptimal compared to a compile-time 2D matrix with regard to memory access and memory localization.

Comment: +1 because of unwarranted downvotes on a perfectly good answer that answers the question.

Comment: @DavidHammen if by “compile-time” you mean “compile-time allocated”, `std::array<std::array<T, N>, M>` has a constant size which is allocated at compile-time and it’s exactly as big as `T[N][M]`.

Comment: @David: You *do* know that `std::array` is a "compile-time" array and has exactly the same layout and memory access as a C-style array, right?

Comment: Except that unlike `T[N]`, `std::array<T, N>` has an interface that doesn’t suck.

Comment: @David: `std::array<T, N>` is *exactly* `T[N]` in *every* respect, except a superior interface, including memory layout and all the rest. Your `T[N][M]` is an array of arrays.

Comment: @DeadMG: "Your `T[N][M]` is an array of arrays". No, it isn't. Read the standard. `T[N][M]` is one contiguous chunk of memory. Neither `boost::ublas` nor Eigen nor any sane math package uses an array of arrays / vector of vectors to represent a matrix where the matrix dimensions are compile-time constants. An array of arrays / vector of vectors is a downright stupid way to go if the dimensions are small, compile-time constants.

Comment: Why is there such prejudice of many C++ programmers against using the simpler, more intuitive, less persnickety C constructs?  Does any C++ compiler implement a warning which alerts about using C constructs?  What about a C++ compiler which can be instructed to give an error?

Comment: @wallyk - *Why is there such prejudice of many C++ programmers against using the simpler, more intuitive, less persnickety C constructs?* It boggles the mind, doesn't it?

Comment: @DavidHammen: An array is a contiguous chunk of `T`. Therefore, substitute `T[N]` for `T`, and it will be obvious that `T[N][M]` is an array of arrays. `std::array<std::array<T, M>, N>` is one statically allocated contiguous chunk of T, of size N * M. Also, the C constructs are decidedly more error prone and less safe, have a truly shitty interface, etc.